# print only part of an array

Tags: php, arrays, printing

I have an array in php called:
    $tmpArrayFechas.

The array when printed outputs like this:

```
[{"fecha":{"0":"2018-12-04"},"id":{"0":"34732"},"quedanplazas": 
{"0":"42"}},{"fecha":{"0":"2018-12-11"},"id": 
{"0":"34733"},"quedanplazas":{"0":"55"}},{"fecha":{"0":"2018-12- 
18"},"id":{"0":"34734"},"quedanplazas":{"0":"52"}}]
```

I only need the id in the array.
I have tried this and many other ways:

```
echo $tmpArrayFechas[0].id["0"];
```

Above give this error:
    Notice: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in 
    /Users/helen/Documents/Web/htdocs/pas/restofform.php on line 51
    [i

Comment: PHP does not use "Dot Notation" for accessing object members.

Comment: with coma same error, doing like this $tmpArrayFechas[0]->id["0"]; get error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: ok, se is duplicated, have read that file, and still don´t get it....
If I do this:
$tmpArrayFechas = json_decode($tmpArrayFechas);
print_r($tmpArrayFechas);
print_r($tmpArrayFechas->id[0]);
outputs this:
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fecha] => stdClass Object ( [0] => 2018-12-04 ) [id] => stdClass Object ( [0] => 34732 ) [quedanplazas] => stdClass Object ( [0] => 42 ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [fecha] => stdClass Object ( [0] => 2018-12-11 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: That is a completely new error. Your `print_r()` clearly shows you that `$tmpArrayFechas` is an indexed array so it is not an object and has no immediate member named `id`. Make sure to fully understand `print_r()`'s output or else you will fail again and again and again.